# Filter Inside UseEffect React Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Im using the `.filter()` method on an object inside of a `useEffect()` method to filter out certain arrays out by name if they exist in a second object. I need to get the difference of arrays back into a `useState()` method. Im using the following and works outside the `useEffect()` method:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getDBData().then( (r) => { setAnotherObj(r); });
  getAPICall().then((r) => {
    let result = r.filter(
      (o1) => !anotherObj.filter((o2) => o1.name === o2.name)
    );
    setOption(result);
  });
}, []);
```

Now that works outside of the `useEffect` method when I add it to an event like onClick, but not inside, it might work one time then it doesn't at all. What am I missing about the `useEffect` method that I need to know why the filtering isn't being done?

Comment: Making API calls in an useEffect hook directly is an anti-pattern

Comment: @Ajay so how would I load my data on page load? Ive seen examples being used inside useEffect

Comment: so many problems with your question. 1. you cant use filter on objects, only arrays. 2. what is anotherObj? (should also be called anotherArr, since ur using .filter on it). 3. Is anotherArr used in state? 4. share the code of the full component

Comment: @SoGoddamnUgly its an array with objects to further clarify. 1) The fact that it does render back results, it is an array. 2) anotherObj, is basically another array with objects, I'm doing a comparison against another one with the same dataset. 3) Yes why it has the "set" prefix. 4) I didnt think I needed to as it seemed like a simple question, but I may be wrong

Comment: Does `anotherObj` change? if so, it should be a dependency for the `useEffect`

Comment: Yes, anotherObj changes depending on what is returned from the DB. But it will contain one or more of the same items as the r (the response). So its filtering out the duplicates from r. I tried adding anotherObj to the dependency, but it went on in an infinite loop. I also added to the post as this may also have an effect as to why @diedu

Answer (score 1):

Replace second `filter` with `find`.
`!anotherObj.filter(o2 => o1.name === o2.name)` will always return `false`, be it has elements or not.

There is no dependency array in the in the `useEffect`, so whenever there is a state change, this `useEffect` gets triggered again.

Finding A-B, filter all the elements of A that are not in B.
`r.filter(o1 => anotherObj.find(o2 => o1.name !== o2.name));` With this it removes all the elements that are common in A and B. And leaves out only elements in A.

Update as follows,

```
useEffect( () => { 
  getAPICall().then( (r) => { 
   const result = r.filter(o1 => anotherObj.find(o2 => o1.name !== o2.name));         
    setOption(result);  
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add the dependency array in my question, I've edited it but it was there already in my real code. Although this now works outside of useEffect, I cannot get it to work inside. It still renders the arrays I'm trying to exclude.

Comment: I miss understood the problem statement, you want to extract all the names that are present in `r` but not in `anotherObj`. In other words you want A-B, all elements of A that are not in B. Correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I need the difference between the two objects rendered back. One object has 14 items, the other get added according to the DB call results. I need the difference of object A minus object B rendered